Cheap Redmi phone can screencast to TCL smart TV but Samsung Galaxy A33 5G can't
Visiting my dad, he has a new TCL C735 / C835 / C935 smart TV and a new Samsung Galaxy A33 5G phone. He's getting older and doesn't know much about either of them.
He also doesn't have any Internet connection to his home other than on his phone and he doesn't know how or want to learn how to use a Wi-Fi hotspot from his phone to his TV.
I thought I'd show him how he could screencast from his phone to his TV though so he doesn't have to watch YouTube videos on his tiny phone screen when the huge screen is right there.
I've barely used features like these but managed to screencast from my cheapo Redmi 10C phone in a few seconds. I did not use Wi-Fi to do this:

Redmi 10C Settings:


Redmi 10C Settings/Connections & Sharing:


Redmi 10C Settings/Connections & Sharing/Interconnectivity/Cast:


I thought it would be just as easy with his name brand phone he paid about 4X for that what I paid for mine.
But I could not find a way to screencast from the Galaxy phone!
Could it be his phone completely lacks this feature? That he needs a special app for it? That it's called something unintuitive instead of "screencast"? That there's some hard-to-find setting I have to change?
Or would it be something else entirely?
I searched in the Google App Store and I Googled for solutions but didn't find anything.
(I also tried the cast feature from the YouTube app, but that seems to be quite different and I didn't get it to work from my phone or his, so this question is not about that.)

I just checked my Galaxy M12 Android 14, and there doesn't seem a built-in casting option (granted, it's a very low-end and runs on a stripped-down OneUI Core instead of OneUI), but based on a quick research, looks like Samsung Android devices can only cast to Samsung Smart TV natively.
